# Beamer's \visible inside a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm using beamer for creating presentations. Inside a TikZ node I'd like to make a part of the content appears afterwards. I'm using the `\visible` command for doing so (I don't want the content to move when the hidden part is made visible).

Here's a small example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \visible<+->{You know\dots}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node{I'm \visible<+->{very} happy. };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The compilation fails on a classic TikZ error `Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?`. However if I replace `\visible` by `\only` or `\alt` the output is produced flawlessly. But that's not what I want :)

There's a possible workaround which consists in defining a new visible command, based on `\alt`:

```
\newcommand<>\myvisible[1]{\alt#2{#1}{\phantom{#1}}}
```

But `\phantom` may have some undesirable side effects (with line breaks for example).

Do you have any better solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem arises due to the grapping of arguments of the node together with the `\visible` command.

In `beamer` a good advice is to

1. Try and insert another group
2. Try with the `fragile` option for the frame
3. Combine 1. and 2.

You simply need to add another group inside.

```
\node {{ I'm \visible<+->{very} happy. }};
% or
\node {\bgroup \dots \egroup};
```

This will correctly produce your decired result.

Comment: Thanks, option 1 works, but not in every case. In TikZ if you add another group in a node, you can't add new lines anymore : `\node[align=center]{{a\\b}};` doesn't compile. Should I ask another question on that issue?

Comment: @kelux, then just do: `\node[align=center] {I'm {\visible<+->{very}}\\happy.};`. Just don't have `\visible` spanning two lines.