# How to update an existing node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm drawing a node and after a `\pause` I'd like to add a label to the node. What I have so far simply repaints the node, but I hope that there is a nicer way:

```
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\begin{figure}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8, auto,swap]
     \node[vertex] (v_1) at (1,2) {$v_1$};
     \pause
     \node[vertex,label={[color=blue]80:$12$}] (v_1) at (1,2) {$v_1$}; %here I have to give name, node text and position again...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: check [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

### Method 1

You can use `beamer`'s overlay commands such as `\visible`

```
\node[vertex,label={[color=blue]80:{{\visible<2>{$12$}}}}] (v_1) at (1,2) {$v_1$};
```

Note that an extra pair of braces `{}` is needed around `\visible` with this method. See [explanation here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64075/18228).

### Method 2

You can define a key, say `visible on`, as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/18228), and use it in the label for your node:

```
\node[vertex,label={[color=blue,visible on=<2>]80:$12$}] (v_1) at (1,2) {$v_1$};
```

where `visible on` is defined as

```
\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
```

---

By the way, when defining a TikZ style, it's better to use `\tikzset` rather than the deprecated `\tikzstyle`. So your style `vertex` can be defined as

```
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt}}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use native TikZ/`beamer` syntax, use the `late options`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8, auto, swap, vertex/.style={circle, fill=black!25, minimum size=20pt, inner sep=0pt}]
     \node[vertex] (v_1) at (1,2) {$v_1$};
     \pause
     \path [late options={name=v_1,label={[color=blue]80:$12$}}];
     % or: \path (v_1) [late options={label={[color=blue]80:$12$}}];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```